# Heroku: Livewire is not defined

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-livewire

I I'm trying to deploy a web app written in Laravel - Livewire to Heroku, the app has launched on Heroku, but when I open the console, I get an error "Livewire is not defined".
I tried the command: heroku run php artisan livewire:publish --assets
or even changing app_url, asset_url in config/livewire.php but neither of them can handle this error.
App runs normally on localhost.
Has anyone had this problem or know how to fix it?

Here is the error code on console:
GET http://nvt-base-api.herokuapp.com/vendor/livewire/livewire.js?id=940557fc56b15ccb9a2d net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
login:81 Uncaught ReferenceError: Livewire is not defined
at login:81:27
(anonymous) @ login:81

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me.
Fix " 'asset_url' => null, " in config/livewire.php to " 'asset_url' => 'public', ".
App will run normally on heroku but will give error "Livewire is not defined" on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just double check you are implementing @livewireScripts and your public path is correct, if not you do the following in AppServiceProvider

```
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
         // return your own correct path.
         return realpath(base_path('../'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check the .htaccess file it should be like this

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).